# Fullcalendar - add data to the bottom section of day cell (fc-daygrid-day-bg)

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

This is the fullcalendar html structure:
[image]

The fullcalendar cells are divided into 3 categories, and for the first 2 I was able to tap into and add custom data/styling:

- `fc-daygrid-day-top` (modified using the `dayCellContent` from CalendarOptions)
- `fc-daygrid-day-events` (modified using the `eventContent` from CalendarOptions)
- `fc-daygrid-day-bg` ???

Is there a way to tap into the third one as well(the highlighted line of code)?

Comment: I am also interested in how to do this but can't find a away to do so.  Were you able to solve it?